# MySQL query not getting executed

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL databases. I am using MySQL for my current project

Here is my query

```
CREATE TABLE FRIENDS (
    F_ID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    USER1_ID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(U_ID),
    USER2_ID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(U_ID),
    TIME_OF_FRIENDSHIP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

When I run this query I get this error.

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-22 -------------------------
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE FRIENDS (
    F_ID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    USER1_ID V' at line 17 

 Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE FRIENDS (
    F_ID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    USER1_ID V' at line 17
          <--- 
 [Executed: 18/11/2020 8:14:46 AM] [Execution: 0ms]
```

Can someone help me out with this problem.

Comment: It is not working, I am getting the same error again

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using MS SQL Server syntax and you try to run it on MySQL. Here is MySQL syntax for creating table with FK.

```sql
CREATE TABLE FRIENDS (
    F_ID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    USER1_ID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    USER2_ID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    TIME_OF_FRIENDSHIP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (USER2_ID) REFERENCES USERS(U_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (USER1_ID) REFERENCES USERS(U_ID)
);
```

Reference https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp